# A lot of 0s at the end of ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript

So, I have these 2 functions:

```
b2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}

str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

And I also have this initial data `ArrayBuffer`:

```
ArrayBuffer(27)
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(27)
0: 68
1: -36
2: -6
3: 31
4: 5
5: -88
6: 104
7: 105
8: 83
9: 38
10: 69
11: 108
12: 22
13: 103
14: -107
15: 68
16: -13
17: 85
18: -116
19: 66
20: -44
21: 110
22: 39
23: 38
24: -20
25: 36
26: -119
```

When I use the `b2str` function passing the `ArrayBuffer` as argument, it gives me this string:
`DÜú¨hiS&ElgDóUBÔn'&ì$`

When I pass the string as an argument to `str2ab`, it returns me the same array, but with a lot of 0s at the end:

```
ArrayBuffer(54)
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(54)
0: 68
1: -36
2: -6
3: 31
4: 5
5: -88
6: 104
7: 105
8: 83
9: 38
10: 69
11: 108
12: 22
13: 103
14: -107
15: 68
16: -13
17: 85
18: -116
19: 66
20: -44
21: 110
22: 39
23: 38
24: -20
25: 36
26: -119
27: 0
28: 0
29: 0
30: 0
31: 0
32: 0
33: 0
34: 0
35: 0
36: 0
37: 0
38: 0
39: 0
40: 0
41: 0
42: 0
43: 0
44: 0
45: 0
46: 0
47: 0
48: 0
49: 0
50: 0
51: 0
52: 0
53: 0
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Uint16Array` instead of an `Uint8Array`. This should align the bytes with the `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: This works if the `ArrayBuffer` has an even number of bytes. If the length of the `ArrayBuffer` is an odd number, it will return me this: *"byte length of Uint16Array should be a multiple of 2"*